# How to get data from multiple mysql tables and make one JSON output

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this PHP code:

```
 try {
      $result = $db->prepare('SELECT ID,masina,marka,model,reg_br,istek_reg,servis FROM mehanizacija WHERE user_id=:user_id');
      $result->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
      $result->execute();

        foreach($result as $r) {
          $temp = array();
          $temp[] = (int) $r['ID']; 
          $temp[] = (string) $r['masina'];
          $temp[] = (string) $r['marka']; 
          $temp[] = $r['model'];
          $temp[] = (string) $r['reg_br'];
          $temp[] = 'Date('.str_replace('-',', ',($r['istek_reg'])).')';
          $temp[] = 'Date('.str_replace('-',', ',($r['servis'])).')';

        $rs = $db->prepare('SELECT sum(radnih_sati) FROM track_meh WHERE user_id=:user_id AND id_meh=:id_meh');
          $rs->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
          $rs->bindParam(':id_meh', $r['ID']); 
          //$rs->bindParam(':radnici', $radnici); 
          $rs->execute();
          $sumRows = $rs->fetchColumn(); 
          $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $sumRows);
 $rs1 = $db->prepare('SELECT sum(kolicina) FROM track_meh WHERE user_id=:user_id AND id_meh=:id_meh');
          $rs1->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
          $rs1->bindParam(':id_meh', $r['ID']); 
          $rs1->execute();
          $sumRows1 = $rs1->fetchColumn(); 
          $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $sumRows1);
          $prosecna = $sumRows1/$sumRows;
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $prosecna. ' l/h');

          $rows[] = $temp;
        }
    $table['data'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;
```

and now I have this JSON output:

```
{"data":[[1,"traktor","IMT","510-td","BG-657 UI","Date(2014, 04, 24)","Date(2014, 02, 18)",53,95,"1.79245283019 l\/h"],[3,"Vrsalica","John Deer","n7","BG 777 hb","Date(2014, 07, 18)","Date(2014, 01, 20)",24,66,"2.75 l\/h"],[4,"prikolica","nema","nema","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",0,0,"0 l\/h"],[5,"traktor","","","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",0,0,"0 l\/h"],[6,"kombajn","Novi","NN","Pi 001 ZN","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",24,50,"2.08333333333 l\/h"],[7,"traktor","mnm","","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",6,9,"1.5 l\/h"],[8,"traktor","","","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",0,0,"0 l\/h"],[9,"alat","","","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",0,0,"0 l\/h"],[10,"traktor","","","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",0,0,"0 l\/h"],[11,"setvo-spremac","","","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",0,0,"0 l\/h"],[12,"traktor","","","","Date(0000, 00, 00)","Date(0000, 00, 00)",0,0,"0 l\/h"]]}
```

What I need to do to transform my JSON output format to this:

```
{"data":[{"ID":"1","masina":"traktor","marka":"IMT","model":"510-td","reg_br":"BG-657 UI","istek_reg":"2014-04-24","servis":"2014-02-18","sumRows":"555", "sumRows1":"333","prosecna":"2.0999"}, etc ...
```

SO as you see my JSON output is wrong, becouse dataTable plugin need data in format like I put above, becouse of that I need to find a way to transform that data in follow format.

Any idea how to do that? I try many different ways but I cant solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

The use of `$temp[]` is giving you a numerical keyed array, which is why the end result is an array of arrays. According to your desired output, you need an array of associative arrays, which will ultimately give you an array of objects (as a string) after the JSON transformation.

Replace each `$temp[]` with `$temp['some_key']`, using the relevant key.

```
$temp['ID'] = (int) $r['ID']; 
$temp['traktor'] = (string) $r['masina'];
```

Comment: So don't store them in `$temp` then. Remove any that you don't want to appear in the JSON.